# Call activity from RecyclerView(Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to call new activity by click event in recycle view.

Here is code, how I do this

This code in Adapter

```
private Activity _context;
 public MovieAdapter(List<Movie> movies,Activity context)
    {
        this.movies = movies;
        _context = context;
    }
```

and here is click event

```
void OnItemClick(int position)
    {
        if (ItemClick != null)
        {
            _context.StartActivity(typeof(Register));
        }
           // ItemClick(this, position);
    }
```

In MainActivity I have

```
 var moviesAdapter = new MovieAdapter(films.results);
```

> Constructor Movie Adapter has 1 argument

How I need to write second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code with:

```
var moviesAdapter = new MovieAdapter(films.results, this);
```

Here you are passing the instance of the caller which in your case is the `MainActivity` class.